# Handling mouseevent in QStatusBar

Tags: qt, qt4

In my statusbar, I have added one `QLabel` inside which I am displaying some message. Now what I want is when I click on that `QLabel` (present inside the `QStatusBar`), the message should disappear..

I have added the label inside statusbar as follows:

```
QLabel *cpyrightlbl= new QLabel();
ui.statusBar->addWidget(cpyrightlbl);
cpyrightlbl->setText("Demo Message");
cpyrightlbl->setStyleSheet("border: 3px");
cpyrightlbl->setFixedWidth(frameGeometry().width());
cpyrightlbl->show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own class which derives from `QLabel` and then reimplement the function `QLabel::mousePressEvent ( QMouseEvent * ev )`.

```
void CMyLabel::mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent * ev )
{
    if( ev->button() == Qt::LeftButton )
    {
        this->clear();
        // or
        // this->setText( "" );
    }

    QLabel::mousePressEvent( ev );
}
```

- [QLabel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qlabel.html)
- [QLabel::mousePressEvent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qlabel.html#mousePressEvent)

Comment: I got the solution for the above one ..
Now i am running through one more problem i.e when i minimize my main application window the status bar message is getting truncated . Is there any way to resolve this issue ? I mean to say the same message shall be displayed without any trucation during minimizing and maximizing .
.